# Why SortBy Values result is wrong?

Tags: java, collections

I'm trying to sort a list by `offerValues` using `compareTo` method.
It works fine it offerValue is a single digit like 8.00, but if offerValue is 20.00 or 15.00, it's considering them as 2(for 20.00) and 1(for 15.00). Don't understand it.

```
Comparator<OfferVO> comparatorAsc = (o1, o2) -> {
    if (o1.getOfferValue() == null && o2.getOfferValue() == null) {
        return 0;
    } else if (o1.getOfferValue() != null) {
        return o1.getOfferValue().compareTo(o2.getOfferValue());
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
};

Collections.sort(offersList, comparatorAsc);
```

**OfferVO.class:**

```
public class OfferVO extends OfferBaseVO implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private String offerValue;

    public String getOfferValue() {
        return offerValue;
    }
    public void setOfferValue(String offerValue) {
        this.offerValue = offerValue;
    }
}
```

**Output sample:**

```
"offerValue": "5.00",
"offerValue": "3.00",
"offerValue": "3.00",
"offerValue": "20.00",
"offerValue": "15.00",
"offerValue": "15.00",
```

Comment: At a guess, `getOfferValue` is returning a `String`, but without more context, it's just a guess

Comment: We need to see the code of `OfferVO`

Comment: can you share the offerVo code and the output you got

Comment: have added OfferVO class

Comment: You can really just use `Comparator.comparing(OfferVO::getOfferValue)`.

Comment: Offer values are `String`s,but it sounds like you expect them to be compared as if they were actually numbers.  If that's the case, why not just store and manipulate them **as** numbers?

Comment: You want to compare numerically, but you use a String to store your number. Strings are sorted lexicographically. Use the appropriate type (a number: double or BigDecimal) to store your numeric value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strings are [compared lexicographical](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo-java.lang.String-) (colloquially alphabetically), not numerically. That means `"10"` will come before `"2"` and so on. If you want to compare the numerical values you'll need to parse the strings into numbers, for instance with [`Double.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score 2):

1) To compare String as numeric value, convert them into numbers in your comparator as `String.compare()` relies on the lexicographical order.

2) Note that your comparator is not symmetric.

The `Comparator.compare()` specification states that :

> The implementor must ensure that sgn(compare(x, y)) == -sgn(compare(y,
>   x)) for all x and y.

Here :

```
else if (o1.getOfferValue() != null) {
                    return o1.getOfferValue().compareTo(o2.getOfferValue());
 }
```

You rely on the non nullity of only `o1.getOfferValue()` to compare the two objects :

To write a more precise numerical comparison about the rounding you should use an epsilon as you compare the floating values such as

```
float epsilon = 0.0001F;
if (o1.getOfferValue() == null && o2.getOfferValue() == null){
    return 0;
} else if (o1.getOfferValue() != null && o2.getOfferValue() != null) {
    return Math.abs(Float.valueOf(o1.getOfferValue()) - Float.valueOf(o2.getOfferValue())) < epsilon)
}
 // TODO 
 // as last you have to decide here how to sort if only one of the value is not null
```

If the rounding is not an issue in the comparison : `Float.compare()` is enough :

```
if (o1.getOfferValue() == null && o2.getOfferValue() == null){
    return 0;
} else if (o1.getOfferValue() != null && o2.getOfferValue() != null) {
    return Float.compare(Float.valueOf(o1.getOfferValue()), Float.valueOf(o2.getOfferValue());
}
```

Comment: `Math.abs(Float.valueOf(o1.getOfferValue()) - Float.valueOf(o2.getOfferValue())) < epsilon)` is very (very) ugly. Why not use `Float.compare` instead ?

Comment: @ortis  It is not mandatory. It is for preventing rounding error. I updated.

Comment: You can prevent rounding errors at all using `new BigDecimal(o.getOfferValue())` (mentioned by JB Nizet in his comment to the question). This will give you the full precision of the numbers.

Comment: @davidxx 
shouldn't it be 
    
           Float.valueOf(o1.getOfferValue())
          .compareTo(Float.valueOf(o2.getOfferValue));

Comment: In fact I mixed both. `Float.compareTo(Float)` will require a boxing float to Float that is not necessary. As null is checked before, `Float.compare(float, float)` is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Used below code:

```
Comparator<OfferVO> comparatorDesc = (o1, o2) -> {
                if (o1.getOfferValue() == null && o2.getOfferValue() == null) {
                    return 0;
                } else if (o2.getOfferValue() != null) {
                    return 
    Double.valueOf(o2.getOfferValue()).compareTo(Double.valueOf(o1.getOfferValue()));
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            };
```